# Android: switch to a different IME programmatically

Tags: android, ime

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/creating-input-method.html#GeneralDesign
reads:

*Because multiple IMEs may be installed on the device, provide a way for the user to switch to a different IME directly from the input method UI.*

Let's assume I have the source of two input methods and can modify it.
I want to let the user switch between them quickly and am ready to reserve a button for that.
How do I *"switch to a different IME directly from the input method UI"?*

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Switching to the previous input method ***from the current input method*** is:

```
//final String LATIN = "com.android.inputmethod.latin/.LatinIME";
// 'this' is an InputMethodService
try {
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) this.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    final IBinder token = this.getWindow().getWindow().getAttributes().token;
    //imm.setInputMethod(token, LATIN);
    imm.switchToLastInputMethod(token);
} catch (Throwable t) { // java.lang.NoSuchMethodError if API_level<11
    Log.e(TAG,"cannot set the previous input method:");
    t.printStackTrace();
}
```

If you want to switch to a particular input method whose ID you know, you may do as the commented-out lines suggest.

EDIT @pRaNaY suggested a single `.getWindow()` in a silent edit (click "edited" below to see the history). I remember that it did not work for Android 2.3; if you consult the docs, you will see that the first call, `InputMethodService.getWindow()` returns a `Dialog` (which is not a subclass of `Window`), and the second call, `Dialog.getWindow()` returns a `Window`. There is no `Dialog.getAttributes()`, so with a single `.getWindow()` it will not even compile.

Comment: but how to get instance of service class for final IBinder token = this.getWindow().getWindow().getAttributes().token;

Comment: @Ram if your project is an InputMethodService, and it is currently selected by the user, this is your service.

Comment: I'm confused, doesn't this solution contradict what @Raghav Sood was saying - that for security reasons this is not allowed?

Comment: @RonenRabinovici the security check is that _`setInputMethod()` can only be called from an application or a service which has a token of the currently active input method._

Comment: From api level 28, you can use `switchToPreviousInputMethod()`, inside `InputMethodService`.

Answer (score 13):

You cannot change the user's currently active IME through code for security reasons, sorry.

However, you can show a system provided dialog to allow the user to select one of the other enabled ones.

```
InputMethodManager imeManager = (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE); 
if (imeManager != null) {
    imeManager.showInputMethodPicker();
} else {
    Toast.makeText(context ,"Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: The mean for you to show a switcher dialog, which will be provided by the system. You cannot do it without showing this dialog.

Comment: Then how will I invoke that switcher dialog? Note that I am writing an input method, not an application.

Comment: Sorry if I miss understand, doesn't the accepted answer provide a solution?

Comment: @RaghavSood if you use this, there as a Set Up Input Methods button if the keyboard is not in list. It has stopped working from Android 7.0 Nougat. :(

Answer (score 0):

If you have rooted device, you can use /system/bin/ime utility.

List all installed input methods: # ime list -a

Set google's keyboard as default:

```
ime set com.google.android.inputmethod.latin/com.android.inputmethod.latin.LatinIME
```