# Android have button on keyboard that switches custom keyboard to user specified default keyboard

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I have a custom keyboard in Android. I want to have a button on my keyboard that when pressed will hide my keyboard and show the keyboard that the user has specified as the default keyboard. (If worst comes to worst, I will accept a solution that just shows the default Android keyboard that is not specified by the user).

I tried this code:

```
 private void showSoftKeyboard()
{
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED,InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
}
```

But that did nothing.

What should I do?

Edit One:

I am documenting my progress in figuring this out.

So far I have figured out how to get the default user set keyboard:

```
String currentKeyboard =  Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.DEFAULT_INPUT_METHOD);
```

Based off of this post: [How to detect if user's keyboard is Swype?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14370882/how-to-detect-if-users-keyboard-is-swype)

I believe there is a method in the `InputMethodManager` class that allows you to set the InputMethod. I believe this is true due to this post: [Android: switch to a different IME programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16684482/android-switch-to-a-different-ime-programmatically)

Now I just have to figure out how to figure out how to get the id of the default keyboard and then I can implement this feature.