# Android soft keyboard is not changing programmatically

Tags: android, switch-statement, android-softkeyboard

I am trying to change the android default keyboard to another soft keyboard that has already installed.

for achieving this task I tried this code,

```
imeManager.setInputMethod(txtSearch.getWindowToken(), 
            "lk.bhasha.helakuru/.SinhalaSoftKeyboard");
```

but the keyboard  is not changing.

How do I switch the android soft keyboard to another already installed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For security reasons, it's not possible to change the keyboard programmatically, unless your application is an IME.

From the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/InputMethodManager.html#Security):

> **A client application can ask that the system let the user pick a new IME, but can not programmatically switch to one itself**. This avoids malicious applications from switching the user to their own IME, which remains running when the user navigates away to another application. An IME, on the other hand, is allowed to programmatically switch the system to another IME, since it already has full control of user input.

Comment: ok thanks, But I want to know keyboard changing is possible or not?

Comment: As I already stated in my post, the answer depends on the type of your application: normally, **no**, but if it's an IME, **yes** (see this https://stackoverflow.com/a/16729473/469983)